# Why is the status of PBS job with dependency 'Hold', not 'Queue'?

Tags: pbs

I used following command to submit my dependent job.

```
qsub current_job_file -W depend=afterany:previous_job_id
```

Then I find out my current job is under status 'H'. And it won't automatically run after the previous job finished. Is it how it suppose to be or I made a mistake somewhere? How can I let it run automatically after the previous job finish?

I also tried the following command. The result is the same.

```
 qsub -W depend=afterany:previous_job_id current_job_file
```

Answer (score 1):

That is how it is supposed to be. If your current job is dependent on another job and the dependency is "after" then it will be held until the other job finishes (or starts depending on what kind of dependency you have used. In your case it is "any" so it will wait for the other job to finish) and then move your current job to "Q" (queued) state for PBS scheduler to consider the job for running.